How to calculate temperature increase in a step motor?
The background is, I'm working in quality, and I just need to be able to tell if someone can burn themselves on the motors built into the product.  I have the datasheet for the motor, and the following parameters:

Is this something as simple as I2R, or is there another back-of-the-envelope calculation that can be used here?  It's nothing that needs to be incredibly accurate, but I do need to be able to tell people if they'll get burnt.

there is no way to tell from specs.  You need to touch it, use the backs of your fingers.

Like @TigerGuy says, you can't tell but two windings with 4.2 amps per winding at 2.1 volts  gives about 18 watts.  Enough to get warm, maybe even hot depending upon the environment.  How about phrasing like "Exercise caution as motor may be hot"?  That will work even if the motor never gets above slightly warm.
